# Linking a query criteria to a value in a local table

Tags: ms-access, query-builder

I have a 5 column table with thousands of rows that I need to be able to filter. In the form where the table is displayed, Form1, I have a text field, Value1, where the table will only display the rows where Column 0 = Value1. If Value1 is blank, all rows will be displayed.

The code below is what is being currently used in the criteria and or field of my query builder and works great:

```
Like [Forms]![Form1]![Value1] & "*"
IsNull([Forms]![Form1]![Value1])
```

My goal is to have the criteria grab the value from a table, rather than a form. I created a form that pops up before Form1 that allows you to insert Value1 then hit Search. The value then goes into [Table1]![Value1] then opens Form1 and displays the filtered results. I am successfully inputting Value1 into Table1 but can't seems to get the query to react to [Table1]![Vale1]. I have tried a few different codes, the code below is an example of one:

```
Like [Tables]![Table1]![Value1] & "*"
IsNull([Tables]![Table1]![Value1])
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Will the local table only ever contain a single record (with three fields)?

Comment: That's what JOINs are for, isn't it ? The DLookup approach below works for small tables, but is highly inefficient. It will crawl to death on larger tables.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `DLookup` function to get the value from the table, like this:

`Dlookup("Value1","Table1")`

This will work fine if you have only one value in the table. If you have multiple values in the table and need to have a specific value, you need to add a filter in the third parameter of the `Dlookup` function.

`Dlookup("Value1","Table1","TableFieldName=" & [Value])`

or, if the criteria value is a string

`Dlookup("Value1","Table1","TableFieldName='" & [Value] & "'")`

or, if the criteria value is a date

`Dlookup("Value1","Table1","TableFieldName=#" & [Value] & "#")`

See the docs also at : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.application.dlookup

Comment: The table displays results only when there are values inputted for some reason, otherwise the table will be blank. To give more information, There are 3 values that the user can input, Value1, Value2, and Value3. The table will display the filtered results only when all 3 values are inputted. You should be able to input one value, two values, three values, or no values and the table will be filtered accordingly. I tried 'Like DLookUp("Value1","Table1")', 'Like DLookUp("Value2","Table1")', 'Like DLookUp("Value3","Table1")', each going in there respected columns in the query builder.

Comment: Try `Like Nz(DLookUp("Value2","Table1"),"") & "*"`, if you values are text based.